# nowrap between font icon (or image) and link

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer, icons, nowrap

I have a link and icon (font) after it. Need prevent wrapping between link and icon: for long link line break should appear between words not between word and icon. I've created parent block with nowrap and inner block with wrapping, it works in FireFox but doesn't work in Chrome and IE (IE10 for example). For test purpose I also created the same layout with image (instead of icon) and have the same result - http://jsfiddle.net/6ak7q/2/ - when I change window size I see that on new line there is only image without any word.

[image]

Maybe related question - [Link arrows dropping to new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995066/link-arrows-dropping-to-new-line), but I can't use background for font icon...
Original code with font-icon:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Glyphicons Regular';
            src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-regular.eot');
            src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-regular.svg#glyphiconsregular') format('svg');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        .glyphicons {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            color: #1d1d1b;
            text-decoration: none;
            *display: inline;
            *zoom: 1;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .glyphicons.nl-icons.unlock {
            font: 12px 'Glyphicons Regular';
            height: 12px;
            padding: 0 5px;
            width: 22px;
        }

        .glyphicons.unlock:before {
            content: "\E205";
        }
//added for old IE
        .glyphicons.unlock {
            zoom: expression( this.runtimeStyle['zoom'] = '1', this.innerHTML = '&#xE205;');
        }

        body {
            font-size: 11px;
        }

        .titleResult {
            white-space: normal;
        }

        .resultHeader {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:30%">
    <div class="resultHeader">
        <span class="titleResult"><a href="example.com">Test long title Test long title Test long title Test
                    long title Test long title Test long title</a></span><span
            class="small nl-icons glyphicons green unlock"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep the icon and text inside one more span and apply `nowrap` class for that.

```css
.titleResult {
    white-space: normal;
}

.resultHeader, .nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:30%">
    <div class="resultHeader">
            <span class="titleResult">Test long title Test
                    long title Test long <span class="nowrap">title <img
                src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" height="15"/></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have a link not text. I've edited question. I thought it is not good to add the icon into <a> tag... I'll use this solution if nothing other help (the link titles are received from other server, so I will need add additional span in php before last word).